# Hot to get low weighs app with many hd images

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm developing an application for Android in visual studio. Currently my application has a main Activity with 1 wallpaper and another Activity with a listView of 200 elements with an image in each of 100x100. That application on the cell phone already weighs 25 MB.
I have seen playstore applications that have many more images and all come in HD and still the application does not weigh more than 10 MB.
Also doing some tests I realized that these applications are increasing in size as I visualize more images.
My question is how to do this? That the application at the beginning weighs little and occupies more space as the user visualizes more and more elements.
PS: I clarify that those playstore applications were quite simple and I doubt very much that the developer has created a web service or a server that sends images by request.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at Glide or Picasso
They are two libraries heavily supported and well in use in the android community.
Their main purpose is to facilitate the usage of images. They handle local images as well as images hosted remotely on some server.

If your images are located on some servers (online galleries, maybe your own google photo gallery), picasso / glide will handle the downloading / caching part.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your imagens to some cloud repository (like AWS S3 or Firebase Storage) without develop a web service and then download the imagens from that. You may use Glide or Picasso (as Charles mentioned) to load the image on memory or even download the RAW PNG or JPG image to the device's internal Storage on the First load (as you mentioned in your examples). To achieve this using Firebase, all you need to do is create an account on Firebase Console, create a project there and follow the instructions on the Storage section. It is extremely simple and Firebase's interface is Very intuitive. They also provide a lot of "get started" video tutorials on their YouTube channel